# How do the DY and DZ pseudo-instructions work in NASM?

Tags: x86, nasm, avx, avx512

In nasm, pseudo-instructions like `db` can be used to declare initialized data. For example:

```
db 0, 1
```

Declares two bytes of initialized data, a 0 followed by a 1.

There are more types beyond `db`. The documentation says:

> DB, DW, DD, DQ, DT, DO, DY and DZ (collectively "Dx" in this documentation) are used, much as in MASM, to declare initialized data in the output file. They can be invoked in a wide range of ways: ... DT, DO, DY and DZ do not accept integer numeric constants as operands.

However, it doesn't give examples of `DY` adn `DZ` use for initialized data.

Let's say I just want to declare a `zmm` register's worth of 0 bytes (64 bytes). How do I do it? As the documentation says "DT, DO, DY and DZ do not accept integer numeric constants as operands.", so `dz 0` doesn't work, but it isn't clear what forms they *do* accept.

Comment: For the record, `times 64 db 0` is one simple readable way to do it, although `times` doesn't work as part of a longer source line.  `dt` accepts FP literals (and emits the 10-byte 80-bit x87 format), but IDK about `do` (XMM) / `dy` / `dz`, so good question about what they're for.

Comment: `times 64 db 0` is how I'm doing it now but I assume times and `rep` are slower than just declaring the 64 bytes in one shot. Not that the difference matters _that much_ but I was more just curious how these are supposed to work as documentation seems sparse. I do find then accept string constants.

Comment: Ah, so possibly useful for padding strings to multiples of 16, 32, or 64 bytes.  Re: slower: NASM build time is generally pretty fast, but I guess it could matter for huge source files, especially machine-generated or with big macro expansions.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you can use string syntax

> Strings enclosed in backquotes support C-style \–escapes for special characters.
>
> ...
>
> The following escape sequences are recognized by backquoted strings:
>
> ...
>
> \xFF        Up to 2 hexadecimal digits - literal byte

So use

```
dz `\x00`
```